# Where to ask my question on moving petting-zoo goats?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question that seems to fall right into the crack between quite a few sites’ scopes:

> In my son’s favourite zoo, there is a goat-petting area with a double-door system to allow humans to access the area without the goats getting out.
>
> Now, I often find myself in the situation that some other visitors were careless and allowed some goat to get between the two doors.
>   Since there often is no personnel around (and I am bored), I want to resolve this situation by nudging the goats back into their area.
>   However, they often are stubborn as, well, goats, and I do not want to harm them by applying too much force.
>
> What is the best way to move such a goat?

So far I considered the following sites for this:

- **[Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**, however, the goats in question are no “animal companions that are cared for in a domestic setting”.
- **[The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**, however, I am not encountering these goats in free nature and they are likely quite different in behaviour from free-ranging goats.
- **[Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**, however, this is not about anything listed on the site’s scope. All [questions about zoos](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoos) seem to be enquiring about the existence or travelling to certain zoos.
- **[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**, however, my question is very applied to what most biologists care about. It would be like asking a question about repairing my bicycle on Physics.
- **[Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**, however, my question is a “conventional *‘how to…’* question about skills that can commonly be learned elsewhere”, namely when training to be a goat herder or petting-zoo attendant.

Is there any other site where my question would be a good fit? Or am I misjudging the scope of any of the aforementioned sites?

Comment: Pets does have a Goats tag (only 4 questions though)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, but petting goats are not pet goats, at least according to the definition of site scope I quoted.

Comment: Maybe you can scare them with a good goat-recipe, in which case Seasoned Advice becomes an option to add to your list ....

Comment: If you generalize the question to *in our back yard we keep goats, how do I move them around when needed* I could argue it fits on pets.se

Comment: So rephrase the question. "My house has a double door system to allow us to get in and out without my pet goat escaping" ...

Comment: Pets has horse questions. Immagonnapingamod - they could use the rep ;)

Comment: Imma straight-up tell you that *you* not applying harm to *them* is only one of the two things you have to worry about when pestering stubborn goats. I got a lesson one day in that when I was 10 or so and I haven’t forgotten it yet.

Comment: The question shouldn't be asked as it is trivial. You simply get on your hands and knees and when they climb on you like you're a rock crawl back into the petting area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Rene pointed out, you can just rephrase it to fit within the scope of Pets. You may wish to point out that you have no 'long-term' control over these goats (ie - you can't train them because you're not around long enough) but we have plenty of questions that ask about other people's pets ('How can I stop my room-mates dog growling at me?' etc)

The question seems like a goat behavioural question: 'How do I move a goat that is stubborn without hurting it?'. The fact that they are in a petting zoo is only relevant because they would be more tame than a regular goat. I would also agree that the fact they are relatively tame is going to make their behaviour pretty different to a wild goat.

Comment: Okay, [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21334/5968) we go.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [goats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goats) tag. If the question is about an animal in the type of setting one would relate to as a pet (a petting zoo is one of those) is within scope. A petting zoo is a concentrated facility to provide people with the experience of petting animals that not everyone can keep as pets. The keyword here is "petting", it's relate and within the scope of [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/).

If the question related to the farming and livestock management related to an commercial concern it would, technically, be out of scope. As Henders [mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315524/310756) if a question is reworded to relate to our relationships with animals as pets.

Even questions about wild animals that come into our care temporarily can be on scope on Pets. For example when an animal is injured, orphaned or strayed. We want to provide a good goto resource for people wanting to know how to care for animals in a range of situations.

It's worth noting Henders and I are both [mods on Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).